# Android devices no longer recognized by PC following Windows update

Tags: android, windows

Yesterday my PC (Windows 8.1) performed an automatic update and now my android devices (a Samsung s4 mini and Samsung Note 8.0 tablet) are not being recognized by Android Studio or Windows in general when plugged in via USB. I have tried the devices on other PCs as they work as normal.

When I plug the devices into the computer I see a charging icon on the phone but no notification of USB connection and no option for selecting between camera and MTP device. The devices also do not appear in Device Manager (not even as unknown devices) or as storage drives in explorer. I attempted to do a system restore but the restore point failed when I tried to launch it and then deleted itself. Re-opening the restore tool now shows that there are no restore points and that the memory allocation for restore points had suddenly  been set to zero (perhaps I have a virus).

The USB ports work for other devices, such as USB drives. I have tried plugging the Android devices into a variety of ports with no success. I have also tried different cables. I use the devices for development, so USB debugging is switched on.

Is there any sort of process that is typically launched by Windows that allows an Android device to be recognized? I am trying to understand what may have happened here and how to fix it. Google searches are turning up nothing without being able to see the devices in Device Manager.

Many Thanks

Comment: Hope you get it fixed, but you're off topic here.  Try either superuser or android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Install or update the driver for the specific device?

Comment: @GabeSechan - Ah, sorry about that. I will be sure to post such questions to the other forums in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievably, I tried a fourth USB cable and connectivity is back. I didn't realize there could be so much variation in a cable.